# Heatmap in PHP, using mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, heatmap

I've currently got a database with just short of 2000 client locations in Australia. What I am trying to do is to display this data on a heatmap, to be embedded into an existing website.

I've done a heap of looking around, and can't seem to find exactly what I'm after.
http://www.heatmapapi.com/sample_googlev3.aspx
http://www.heatmaptool.com/documentation.php

These are along the right lines of what I want to achieve, however I cannot see these working with data from a mysql database (require the data to be hard-coded, or uploaded through CSV files).

Has anyone come across this sort of thing before, or managed to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Both of the examples you provide would potentially work.

With the first you would need to use the data you have to dynamically generate the javascript, or at least the values that go into the javascript.

The second is probably the better option. You would provide a path to the script that would dynamically generate a CSV file.